# Construction of a function of a countable set of Cantor sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, functions, solution-verification, cantor-set

The following is an exercise from Bruckner's Real Analysis:

> Construct a functions $ f : [ 0 , 1 ] \to [ 0 , 1 ] $ as follows. Let $ \{ I _ n \} $ be an enumeration of the open intervals in $ [ 0 , 1 ] $ having rational endpoints. For each $ n \in \mathbb N $, let $ K _ n \subset I _ n $ be a cantor set of positive Lebesgue measure such that the sequence $ \{ K _ n \} $ is pairwise disjoint and $ \sum _ { n = 1 } ^ \infty \lambda ( K _ n ) = 1 $. Define $ f _ n $ on $ K _ n $ to be continuous on $ K _ n $, nondecreasing, and such that $ f _ n ( K _ n ) = [ 0 , 1 ] $. Let
> $$ f ( x ) = \begin {cases}
> f _ n ( x ) \text , & \text {if } x \in K _ n \text ; \\
> 0 \text , & \text {if } x \in [ 0 , 1 ] \setminus \bigcup _ { n = 1 } ^ \infty K _ n \text .
> \end{cases} $$
> $ \ $ (a) Show that $ f $ is Lebesgue measurable.
> $ \ $ (b) Show that $ f ( I ) = [ 0 , 1 ] $ for every open interval $ I \subset [ 0 , 1 ] $.
> $ \ $ (c) Using the sets $ K _ n $, find continuous functions on $ [ 0 , 1 ] $ that approximate $ f $ in the Lusin sense.
> $ \ $ (d) Does there exists $ g \in \mathcal B _ 1 $ such that $ g = f \ \lfloor \text {a.e.} \rfloor $?

I represent only ideas I have for each part and if I am in a right track I'll start fill the gaps and make them rigorous.

(a) $ \{ f < a \} = f ^ { - 1 } ( I \cap [ 0 , 1 ] ) $ for some $ I \subset \mathbb R $. I don't know if $ f $ is continuous but if is, then $ f ^ { - 1 } ( I \cap [ 0 , 1 ] ) = f ^ { - 1 } ( I ) \cap [ 0 , 1 ] $ is some open interval in $ [ 0 , 1 ] $ hence there are a set of disjoint intervals each containing some $ K _ n $ and $ J = \bigcup _ n K _ n $. And countable union of a sequence of $ K _ n $ is measurable. Since $ a \in \mathbb R $ was arbitrary so $ f $ is Lebesgue measurable.

(b) Each open interval $ I $ in $ [ 0 , 1 ] $ equals a disjoint union of intervals each contains some $ K _ n $ and image of each $ K _ n $ is $ [ 0 , 1 ] $ by $ f _ n $ and $ f = f _ n $ when restricted to each $ K _ n $, so $ f ( I ) = \bigcup _ { n = 1 } ^ \infty [ 0 , 1 ] = [ 0 , 1 ] $.

(c) Because $ \sum _ { n = 1 } ^ \infty \lambda ( K _ n ) = 1 < + \infty $ so there is some $ N $ such that $ \sum _ { n = N } ^ \infty \lambda ( K _ n ) = \epsilon $, and $ \bigcup _ { n = 1 } ^ \infty K _ n $ is closed with a measure differs $ 1 - \epsilon $ and $ f $ on that is continuous since it is on each $ K _ n $ and can be extend to a continuous $ g $ on $ [ 0 , 1 ] $ by Tietze extension theorem.

(d) Probably there is no Baire-1 $ g $ because there is a theorem that if $ f $ is finite a.e. and measurable on $ X $ then there exists Baire-2 $ g $ such that $ f = g $ a.e. and no similar theorem was for Baire-1 in the same book!

A detailed guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Base**: The hypothesis of the exercise:

1. Every open interval with rational endpoints is in the enumeration $\{I_n\}$
2. For every open interval $I_n$ with rational endpoints there is a Cantor set $K_n \subset I_n$  of positive Lebesgue measure.
3. The sequence $\{K_n\}$  is pairwise disjoint.
4. $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda(K_n) =1$.
5. $f_n$ is defined on $K_n$.
6. $f_n$ is continuous and non-decreasing.
7. $f_n(K_n)=[0,1]$

The exercise does **not** ask to prove that those hypothesis can be actually satisfied (they can, but it is not part of the exercise to prove it). For the exercise as stated we must assume those hypothesis.

**item (a)** For each $r \in \Bbb N$ define

$$g_r(x) = \left \{ \begin{array}[c,r] \;f_n(x)  & \text{, if } x \in K_n  \text{ and }  n \leq r \\
0  & \text{, if }x \in  [0,1] \setminus \bigcup_{n=1}^r K_n
\end{array} \right .$$

Since, the sequence $\{K_n\}_n$ is pairwise disjoint, it is clear that $f$ and $g_r$ are well-defined as functions. Moreover, it is clear that for all $r$, $g_r$ is Lebesgue measurable and $\{g_r\}_r$ converges pointwise to $f$. So $f$ is Lebesgue measurable.

**item (b)** Given any open interval $I \subseteq [0,1]$, then there is an open interval $I_s$ with rational endpoints, such that $I_s \subseteq I$. So, we have $K_s \subseteq I_s \subseteq I$. Then $[0,1] = f(K_s) \subseteq f(I)$

On the other hand, it is immediate that $f(I) \subseteq [0,1]$. So we have, $f(I)=[0,1]$.

**item (c)** Since, for each $r \in \Bbb N$, $K_1, \cdots K_r$ are disjoint closed sets, and, for each $n \leq r$, $f_n$ is a continuous function defined on $K_n$, there is a continuous function $h_r$ such that $h_r(x) = f_n(x)$, if $ x \in K_n $   and   $n \leq r$.
Note that  $\bigcup_{n=1}^r K_n$ is a closed set and , for all $x \in  \bigcup_{n=1}^r K_n$, we have $h_r(x) = f(x).

Since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda(K_n) =1$, we have
$$\lambda \left ([0,1] \setminus \bigcup_{n=1}^r K_n \right) = 1 - \sum_{n=1}^r \lambda(K_n) = \sum_{n=k+1}^\infty \lambda(K_n)$$

Given any $\varepsilon >0$, let $r$ be such that $\sum_{n=k+1}^\infty \lambda(K_n) < \varepsilon$.  Then  $\lambda \left ([0,1] \setminus \bigcup_{n=1}^r K_n \right) < \varepsilon$. So the continuous functions $h_r$ approximate $f$ in Lusin sense.

**item (d)** For all $n$, since $K_n$ is compact, let $M_n = \max K_n$  and $m_n = \min K_n$. Since, for all $x \in K_n$, $f(x) = f_n(x)$ and $f_n$ is continuous on $K_n$, non-decreasing and $f_n(K_n)=[0,1]$, we have:

1. $f(m_n) = 0$ and $f(M_n) =1$.
2. for all $\varepsilon >0$, there is $\delta >0$ such that $f([m_n, m_n+\delta)\cap K_n) \subset [0,\varepsilon)$ and $f((M_n-\delta,M_n]\cap K_n) \subseteq (1-\varepsilon,1]$.

Suppose that $g=f$ a.e..

Since $K_n$ is a Cantor set of positive measure, we have that $[m_n, m_n+\delta)\cap K_n$ and $(M_n-\delta,M_n]\cap K_n$ both have positive measure (this is a consequence of the construction Cantor sets with positive measure). So, there is $x \in [m_n, m_n+\delta)\cap K_n$ such that $g(x) =f(x) \in [0,\varepsilon)$  and there is $y \in (M_n-\delta,M_n]\cap K_n$ such that $g(y)=f(y) \in (1-\varepsilon,1]$.

So, for all $K_n$ and all $\varepsilon >0$, there are $x, y \in K_n$ such that  $g(x) \in [0,\varepsilon)$ and $g(y) \in (1-\varepsilon,1]$.

So, for all $\varepsilon >0$ and all $I\subset [0,1] $, $I$ an open interval, we have that there is at least on $K_n \subset I$ (see beginning of item (b)). So, there are $x, y \in I$ such that  $g(x) \in [0,\varepsilon)$ and $g(y) \in (1-\varepsilon,1]$.

So, $g$ is discontinuous in every point of $[0,1]$. But, Theorem 1.19 i Brucker's Book, we know that, if $g$ was Baire 1 function, then the set points where $g$ is discontinuous should be of first-category. But $[0,1]$ is not of first category. So $g$ is not a Baire 1 function.

So, we have prove that if $g=f$ a.e. then $g$ is not  a Baire 1 function.

So, the answer to item (d) is NO. There is no Baire 1 function $g$ such that $g=f$ a.e..

Comment: Thank you very much Ramiro, I will study your answer now and I will write my questions, if any.

Comment: For (b), not *any* interval contains a cantor set of positive measure o.w. they would be overlapping, since $I$ is arbitrary how do you know it's one of the those contains $K_n$?

Comment: For (d), 1- in the paragraph of starting with *"Since K_n is a Cantor set of ..."*, why intersection of two positive measure sets is a positive measure set? 2- in the paragraph of starting with *"So, for all ε>0 ..."*, what if $I$ may not be one of those fully contain a $K_n$? 3- How do you conclude then *"g is discontinuous in every point of [0,1]"* (First, I thought writing $y$ instead of $x$ three times in (d) were typos but maybe answer to this question lies in that replacement?)

Comment: For (b)  Any open inteval contains  at least one of the $K_n$.  The open intervals may overlap, the sets $K_n$ do not overlap.

Comment: The proof that any open interval contains at least one of the $K_n$ is exactly what is presented at the beginning of item (b): "Given any open interval $I \subseteq [0,1]$, then there is an open interval $I_s$ with rational endpoints, such that $I_s \subseteq I$. So, we have $K_s \subseteq I_s \subseteq I$".

Comment: For (d) 1. I have never said or used the the intersection of two positive measure sets is a positive measure set.  What I wrote is : "Since $K_n$ is a Cantor set of positive measure, we have that $[m_n, m_n+\delta)\cap K_n$ and $(M_n-\delta,M_n]\cap K_n$ both have positive measure".  This is a consequence of the construction Cantor sets with positive measure.   (I added to the answer short comment between parenthesis  highlighting this).

Comment: For (d) 2. All open interval contains (fully) at least one of the $K_n$.

Comment: To point which part I'm asking there are 5 ending paragraph starting with "so" and in the first 2, you consider x and **y** at the beginning then conclude on only x. Are they typos?

Comment: Yes, my confusion on (d)2 was a repetition of my confusion on (b)

Comment: For (d) 3. There are three typos in in this part. I fixed them. Thanks. Hope now it is clear that **every** open interval contains  a pair of points $x, y$ such that $g(x)$ close to $0$ and  $g(y)$ close to $1$. So $g$ is discontinuous everywhere.